# how to create a zero button in calculator in windows form calculator

Tags: c#, calculator

I am a student. I have a trouble in creating my Zero Button. The scenario is this, we should create a zero button and when you run and click it, it should not show excess Zeros just like this ... 000000000 ... up to how may times you click the zero button. I want to know how to create a Zero button and when you run and click it, it shows only one Zero (0). Our teacher said that there is no number like this ... 00001.111 or 000.15 or 0005 or anything that starts with a lot of Zero. But I still want my Zero button to function like this ... 100 or 5000 or 0.0006 and all kinds of multiple Zero in a number. Thanks a lot!

Thanks everyone. This is my wrong solution.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //    oneBtn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
    //    twoBtn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
    //    threeBtn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
    //    fourBtn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
    //    fiveBtn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
    //    sixBtn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
    //    sevenBtn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
    //    eightBtn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
    //    nineBtn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        zeroBtn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
    //    pointBtn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
    }
```

and

```
 void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;

            switch (btn.Name)
            {
    //            case "oneBtn":
    //                textBox_output.Text += "1";
    //                break;
    //            case "twoBtn":
    //                textBox_output.Text += "2";
    //                break;
    //            case "threeBtn":
    //                textBox_output.Text += "3";
    //                break;
    //            case "fourBtn":
    //                textBox_output.Text += "4";
    //                break;
    //            case "fiveBtn":
    //                textBox_output.Text += "5";
    //                break;
    //            case "sixBtn":
    //                textBox_output.Text += "6";
    //                break;
    //            case "sevenBtn":
    //                textBox_output.Text += "7";
    //                break;
    //            case "eightBtn":
    //                textBox_output.Text += "8";
    //                break;
    //            case "nineBtn":
    //                textBox_output.Text += "9";
    //                break;
                case "zeroBtn":
                    textBox_output.Text += "0";
                    break;
    //            case "pointBtn":
    //                if (!textBox_output.Text.Contains("."))
    //                    textBox_output.Text += ".";
    //                break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry for the inconvenience, Unexpected error occured. Details:" +
                ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

and this is the keypress

```
private void textBox_output_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        int keycode;
        keycode = e.KeyChar;
        if (keycode >= 48 && keycode <= 57 || keycode == 8 || keycode == 32 || keycode == 46)
        {
            if (keycode == 46)
                ++trackkeypoint;
            if (trackkeypoint > 1)
            {
                if (e.KeyChar == '.' && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                    --trackkeypoint;
                }
            }
        }
        else e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: 0 button in what? you need to show your *relevant* code

Comment: @Ladica if you want to get any reasonable answer here you should tell us a bit of what you tried so far and where you ran into problem - if you can show us the right portion of the offending code would be great

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/32968-basic-calculator-in-c%23/

Comment: Just a little tip (that might not apply) - instead of trying to deal with adding a zero to a textbox, try to separate out your calculator code into tiers. The presentation logic and the calculator logic can be separated out into multiple parts, that way you don't need to worry about whether to check for a zero when adding it to a textbox. Perform your calculations in a calculator class that accepts input and provides output, then take the output and format it into a textbox - you might find the problem solves itself to some degree (i.e. format the number/output itself, don't change the input)

Comment: Very much appreciated, Sir @mybirthname and Sir Sayse. Your codes all work in the GUI of my program but then it seems it does not affect the numerical keypad of the keyboard. I still encounter multiple Zeros like ... 00000.0005 when trying to use my keyboard. Thank You Very Much!

Comment: @angeloLadica You should show us how you add the numbers when you are using keypad of the keyboard and where you are using trackkeypoint.

Comment: @angeloLadica you should make the same check when you press the key

Comment: Sir @mybirthname, I use your code in the calculator though it is not enough to solve the problem. I ask Google how to apply it in the keypad then Google says, I should use KeyDown Event. There, my problem was solved. Thank You Sir!

Comment: Sir @Sayse I also apply your codes and add the KeyDown Event. Thank You Much Sir!

Comment: @angeloLadica - No worries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the button click(zero button) you should check two things. First if you have separator '.' which you do with IndexOf method of string. If this return > 0 you have "." and should add 0. After that if you don't have "." in the else method check if the string doesn't have value and add zero if it is true. If the string is not empty and doesn't start with 0 again add zero.

```
case "zeroBtn":
if(textBox_output.Text.IndexOf(".") > 0)
{
    textBox_output.Text+="0";
}
else
{
    //edit: thanks for the comment
    if(textBox_output.Text.ToString() == "")
    {
         textBox_output.Text+="0";
    }
    else if(!textBox_output.Text.StartWith("0"))
    {
        textBox_output.Text+="0";
    }
    else
    {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

About your edit when you are using the key:
You should make the same checks when the keycode == 48 ( I think this was the code for 0).

Comment: who said that there is a `number` (if there is you don't have to do anything besides `number.ToString()` ...

Comment: @CarstenKönig, you are right in this case you should add one more check I will add it, in the answer

Comment: so what is number? A string? If so why convert to string?

Comment: I don't think you understood - what is your `number`? Assuming it is indeed an `Double` or even a `Int` this will now produce `"05"` if the number was `5` and of course you *cannot possible answer the question right now*

Comment: @CarstenKönig okay I understand you now. I will change it in proper way.

Comment: @mybirthname don't - you will never answer this question - you don't know a thing about the OPs implementation details you can only rewrite his complete app ... and I think you need some unit-tests in there yourself :P

Comment: @CarstenKönig you are right , I assume what he needs. If he post some code I will change my answer. Thanks for your critic, I will have your comments in my mind for the future.It is always nice to find nice guy here :)

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using winforms but you need to add extra handling for your zero button, something like the following

```
//If textbox starts doesn't start with 0 or Textbox
//contains a decimal point then it is ok to add a zero
if(!textBox_output.Text.StartsWith("0") || textBox_output.Text.Contains("."))
    textBox_output.Text += "0";
```

You could also add extra error handling for when the textbox is empty to allow for a zero to be added, as well as other handling on the other numbers to replace an existing zero with the number

```
if(textBox_output.Text.Length <= 1)
    textBox_output.Text = "1";
else
    textBox_output.Text += "1";
```